# React - How do i persist a page url after refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, url-routing, react-link

In my react app, i have stored the respective page names in the local storage depending on the clicked page name i.e for a route say `http://localhost:3000/Products` i have stored the name **Products** in the localstorage whenever i click on the page **Products**.

I want whenever i have a page refresh, instead of being redirected to the home page `/`, my page persists on the page i was by confirming with the value in my localstorage.

My way does not work.

```
<NavLink to="/localStorage.getItem("selectedItem")" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
   <MenuItemComponent
       title="Products"
       icon={IconProducts}
       onClick={() => this.onItemClicked("Products")}
       active={localStorage.getItem("selectedItem") === "Products"}
    />
</NavLink>
```

From the above code, i want the page to direct me to `http://localhost:3000/Products` since the value of **localStorage.getItem("selectedItem")** is **Products**

Comment: By default, the URL *shouldn't* change when you refresh a page, so some setting of yours is preventing this, redirecting you to `/` when you refresh. The code you show does not redirect in any way; it simply sets a boolean attribute on a menu link.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even see that quotes mess until now. You can use `to={"/" + localStorage.getItem("selectedItem")}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get value from LocalStorage but you are using plain string. Should be like this:

```
const AppNaVLink = () => {
    const link = `/${localStorage.getItem("selectedItem") ?? ''}`
    return (
        <NavLink to={link} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <MenuItemComponent
                title="Products"
                icon={IconProducts}
                onClick={() => this.onItemClicked("Products")}
                active={localStorage.getItem("selectedItem") === "Products"}
            />
        </NavLink>)
}
```